# Count BB code occurence

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to count number of occurence of BB code like word (example: **[b] [/b]**).
I tried

```
(str.match(/\[b\]/g)  str.match(/\[\/b\]/g))
```

None of this worked, please help !!!

`Edit`

```
document.getElementById('textarea').value = 'HIiiiiiiiiiii [b]BOld[/b]';
var str = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
```

Answer:

```
if (str.match(/\[b\]/g).length ==  str.match(/\[\/b\]/g)).length) {alert("Fine");}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace occurences until there aren't any; keep track of the amount on the way:

```
var regexp = /\[[a-z]\](.*?)\[\/[a-z]\]/i;
var str = "test [b]a[/b] test [i]b[/i] [b]d[/b] c";
var newstr = str;
var i = 0;
while(regexp.test(newstr)) {
    newstr = newstr.replace(regexp, "");
    i++;
}
alert(i); // alerts 3
```

Comment: I've 2 BB code [b] and [i] , can you modify your code for that ?

Comment: @Sourav: Yes, instead of `b` you can use `[a-z]` which represents any letter.

Comment: @Sourav: You cannot execute two functions after each other like `func1() func2()`. You ought to create one regexp.

Answer (score 2):

This regex will match a BB code opening tag:

```
str.match(/\[[a-z]*\]/g)
```

**Edit:** Here's some code that will do exactly what you want including creating an array of errors listing all missing closing tags. This code uses the [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) library for the groupBy() call.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craigm/hqqT8/)

```
var bbcode = 'HI[i]iii[i]iii[/i]iii [b]BOld[/b] yahhh [img]url[/img]';
var matches = bbcode.match(/\[[a-z]*\]/g); //get the matches

var tags = _.groupBy(matches, function(val) {
    val = val.substring(1, val.length-1);
    return val;
});

var errors = [];

for (var tag in tags) {
    var regex = '\\\[/' + tag + '\\\]'; 
    if (bbcode.match(regex).length != tags[tag].length) {
        errors.push('Missing a closing [/' + tag + '] tag');
    } 
}

console.log(errors);
```

Comment: I'll actually count occurrence of all the tags to make sure all code have been closed [occurrence Of[B] == occurrence of [/b]]

Comment: I updated my answer with code that does exactly what you're looking for.